# Contact From 7 Custom Validation Issues

Tags: customization, plugin-contact-form-7

Here is the situation: I have to make a textarea a required field when the user selects "Other" in a dropdown. That does work, however whenever I try to chec if the validation on all other fields BEFORE  works... well it doesn't .. It doesn't say the user should fill it up, although its mostly required fields. It does work when I add `remove_filter("blabla", "blabla", 10, 2);` but then the custom validation does not work. I hope you guys have an idea where this might be coming from ... that's my code

```php
add_filter("wpcf7_validate_textarea", 'custom_text_validation_filter', 10, 2);
function custom_text_validation_filter ( $result, $tag )
{
    $result = new WPCF7_Validation();

    if ( $tag->name != "comment" )
    {
        return $result;
    }
    else
    {
        $reclReason = isset( $_POST['reason']) ? $_POST['reason'] : ' ';
        $comment = isset($_POST['comment']) ? $_POST['comment'] : ' ';

        if ( $reclReason == 'Other*' && $comment == '' )
        {
            $result->invalidate($tag->name, "Please fill in the required field!");
        }
        else
        {
            $result['valid'] = true;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

also without the **else** at the end (making the field valid otherwise) it also doesn't work, it says it's invalid although there has been something written in..

Comment: Did you check all the ```$_POST``` values (reason and comment) for the expected values? Also you set $comment as space and check if it it's empty.

Comment: @moped yes, they are fine. Hm, you're right. The client changed their decision and would just like to have a "info" text under the textarea when "other" is chosen. I made that with JavaScript and it worked. So if someone else is having the same issue like me, maybe they find their solution here :) Still that doesn't answer why the validation on all other fields doesn't work..